# Automatically pressing enter and y in emacs when prompted for input

Tags: python, keystrokes

In `python.el` there is a command `(python-shell-switch-to-shell)` that opens an ipython shell.

Problem is, it first asks me where to start the REPL and then whether to make a dedicated process. I always answer `<RET>` and `y`. Is there a way to send these signals to emacs automatically?

(I know there are other workarounds, but modifying the `python layer` in spacemacs is probably too much of a bother.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get this behavior when I tried running this, but a simple thing to try is `C-x (` or `kmacro-start-macro`. Then enter the three commands, `(python-shell-switch-to-shell)` `<RET>`, and `y` and finish up with `C-x )` or `kmacro-end-macro`.

In the future you can run `C-x e` to redo that key sequence.

If all that works, then you may want ot go one step further and `M-x name-last-kbd-macro` will assign a name it, and write it out.

See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Basic-Keyboard-Macro.html

Comment: Wow, probably just what I was looking for. This sounds like an awesome way to create custom perspectives: https://github.com/nex3/perspective-el

Comment: @TheUnfunCat perspective is an interesting idea that I might try sometime for debug sessions, e.g. https://github.com/rocky/emacs-dbgr